# Running a Scheduled Azure WebJob Manually

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have a scheduled WebJob in Azure that runs nightly. Occasionally, I find that I need to run this job during the day at arbitrary times.

I would like to be able to manually re-run the job when I feel like it. Is this possible? I can see in the portal that the scheduler is set to hit the URL:

> https://XXX.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredjobs/YYY/run

using a `POST`. I have tried to hit this URL myself. If I do it as a `GET`, I get a 404, and if I try a `POST` then I get an authorisation failure:

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials

I could probably construct the necessary headers or whatever to do the auth, but this feels like yak shaving.

This seems (to me) like a trivial use case, and one that surely there's a button for somewhere in the Azure portal or Kudo?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is authentication required on the request (you should be happy about that :)) [This post](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2015/05/scheduled-webjob.html) shows how to form the correct basic auth URL to invoke your job, and also explains how things work behind the scenes which may interest you.

However, **you can also run your job from the portal**. If you right click in the portal on the job you want to run, you'll see a "Run" context menu item. Not very discoverable I know :(

Comment: Yes, authentication is obviously A Good Thing™ on those calls, just wasn't fond of the idea of having to write code to add the auth when a simple button in the UI should have been there! Thanks for the heads up on the context menu, I'd completely missed it.

Comment: In the new 'crappy' portal, go to your App > WebJobs, click the Job in the list and then Run at the top.